# Open a static Html string (builded up at runtime) from code behind

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

there is a smooth way to open a static html string from code behind whitout writing it to a file?
At the moment i'm doing something like below:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\\mypath\\test.html",false))
 {
      sw.Write(my_html_string); //I build 'my_html_string' inside the code
 }
 Response.Redirect("http://mysite/mypath/test.html");
```

but what i'd like to do is something like:

```
Page.Show(my_html_string);
```

without wasting time writing it to a file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most raw way for doing this is via an `IHttpHandler`.

In Visual Studio via menu: Add > New Item ... > Generic Handler.
You end up with an `.ashx` and a corresponding `.ashx.cs`codebehind file where you write your code.

You navigate to `http://yourwebite/<nameOfYourHttpHandler>.ashx` to see the rendered html.
An `HttpHandler` can be part of routing and can also accept querystring parameters.

**MyHandler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyHandler.ashx.cs" Class="PFX.MyHandler" %>
```

**MyHandler.ashx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace PFX
{
    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Implement logic to build your html string here.
            String html = "<html><head></head><body><b>foobar</b></body></html>";

            // Set any appropriate http-headers here.
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";            
            context.Response.Write(html);
        }

        public Boolean IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

**== EDIT BY LEGION ==**

The above code works perfectly, but if you need to pass some value from previous ASPX page to the handler (like me) you need to do like below:

**previousPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     String my_html_string = string.empty;
     //Code that build the html String
     HttpContext.Current.Application["my_key_name"] = my_html_string;
     Response.Redirect("~/myHandler.ashx");
}
```

**MyHandler.ashx.cs**

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.Write(context.Application["my_key_name"]);
        }

        public Boolean IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You open me a new marvellous world :D
Is not exactly what i need but with two easy changes i reach my goal, if you agree I can edit your answer adding my changes and i mark it as Accepted :)

Comment: It's all yours to make this answer fit your question :)